# Tanuki Wrapper service, unable to set the jvm port

Tags: java, jvm, wrapper

We have a wrapper service which runs on unix, at the moment the wrapper service assigns the wrapper.jvm.port automatically.

What I want is to control this port,

After reading http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-jvm-port.html#minmax

I tried setting the

> > wrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
> >
> > wrapper.jvm.port.max=31999

in the wrapper.conf file

but for some reason it still assigns jvm port randomly. I was expecting the port number between 31000 - 31999, but this is not the case.

how ever the wrapper.port has no issues if I try to set the wrapper.port

> > wrapper.port.min=31000
> >
> > wrapper.port.max=31999

this works fine

Question is, does anyone know why the jvm port settings not working?

Comment: What version of the wrapper are you using?

Comment: Hi Alan, not sure, will check it tomorrow. by the way just was going through the tanuki wrapper change log, looks like wrapper.jvm.port been added since: Version 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

wrapper.jvm.port or wrapper.jvm.port.min/max is only supported starting from tanuki wrapper Version 3.2.0 onwards....